# Add email to PayPal's DoDirectPayment request

Tags: paypal

I'm using the [PayPal PHP SDK](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php) to do a `DoDirectPayment` request and [the example code](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php/blob/master/samples/DirectPayment/DoDirectPayment.php) and the class documentation doesn't explain how to add an email address to the request. Is that possible somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The email address can be supplied using the `Payer` property on `PayerInfoType` [as explained here](https://github.com/paypal/codesamples-php/blob/master/Merchant/sample/code/DoDirectPayment.php).